# How to delete FTP user in ssh?

Tags: ssh, ftp, centos

I am accessing dedicated server **(centOS)** through ssh. I have created few FTP accounts to give them temporary access to change files. Now I don't need it and I want to **delete FTP user** that I have created before through SSH.

I don't know the commands to delete FTP users. Please help me.

Comment: You are likely to get better advice on superuser.com - have voted this answer be moved there.  You should also tell us how you created the users and whether they should retain other privileges on the system.

Comment: i added user using "useradd" command, i given them write permission to few directories but i now i want to completely delete this user. the should be able to access anything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
userdel USERNAME
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: @aakashdodiya Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if you like it.